# smooth convex function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $f(x, y)$ is a smooth convex function and $f(0, 0) = f(1, 0) = f(0, 1) = 0$.

(a) What do you know about $f (1/2, 1/2)$ ?

(b) What do you know about the second derivatives $a=∂^2 f/∂x^2 $ , $b=∂^2 f/∂x ∂y $ and $c=∂^2 f/∂y^2 $ ?

Comment: So, what do you know? Can you share your thoughts?

Comment: I know that second derivatives define the convexity of a function. However, I do not know how to apply it because I could not find such example in the textbook I am studying "Linear algebra and learning from data".

Comment: Do you know what the definition of convexity is? There is a definition that doesn't involve derivatives.

Comment: I know we also can say if the line connecting points inside the convex set is fully inside the convex set, the set is a convex. However, I am not sure if it is also applicable in 3d ! plus, I still do not know about the value of $f(x,y)$ in the point $(0.5 , 0.5)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with the various definitions of [convexity of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables) (which is related to, but not the same as the definition of convexity of a set).

For a convex function of two variables, the definition of convexity is
$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) x', \lambda y + (1-\lambda) y') \le \lambda f(x,y) + (1-\lambda) f(x', y'),
\qquad \text{for all $(x,y), (x',y')$ and all $\lambda \in [0,1]$}$$
Graphically, this means that the secant line connecting $(x,y, f(x,y))$ and $(x', y', f(x',y'))$ lies above the graph of $f$. Applying this definition to part (a) will immediately tell you something about $f(1/2, 1/2)$.

If $f$ is smooth and convex, then the Hessian is positive semi-definite. [You should do some investigation on why this follows from the definition of convexity.] Knowing this, solving (b) just involves writing the condition "the Hessian of $f$ is positive semi-definite" in terms of $a, b, c$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will go for what you said and I hope I can solve it

Comment: could we say $f(1/2, 1/2) < f(x,y)$ and for part b we say $a>0$ and $c > 0$ and $b < 0$ ( to be p.semi.Definite) ?